# Solving: Error: ctree model: Mismatch in number of predictions and test labels

Tags: r, error-handling

Essentially, for my program, I am supposed to create a script that takes input from a csv file "bank.csv", and with it, I am supposed to plot bar graphs comparing the accuracy, precision, recall, and f1score of four classifiers, namely; ctree, J48, linear, and k-NN. While running this code, I have run into a few errors I was able to solve however, I am now stuck on the error aforementioned in the title.

The code is as follows:

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(data.table)  # for data handling
library(caret)       # for data partitioning and model evaluation
library(party)       # for Ctree
library(RWeka)       # for J48 Tree
library(class)       # for k-NN

# Load the data
data <- fread("C:/users/ahshan/downloads/bank.csv")

# Select only numeric variables and target variable
numeric_vars <- c("age", "balance", "day", "duration", "campaign", "pdays", "previous")
data_numeric <- data[, c(numeric_vars, "y"), with = FALSE]

# Normalize numeric attributes
data_numeric[, (numeric_vars) := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols = numeric_vars]

# Convert target variable to factor with consistent levels
data_numeric$y <- factor(data_numeric$y, levels = c("no", "yes"))

# Split the data into training and testing sets
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data_numeric$y, p = .8, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainData <- data_numeric[trainIndex, ]
testData <- data_numeric[-trainIndex, ]

# Prepare features and labels for training
train_features <- trainData[, -ncol(trainData), with = FALSE]
train_labels <- trainData$y
test_features <- testData[, -ncol(testData), with = FALSE]

# Train the models and evaluate

test_labels <- factor(testData$y, levels = c("no", "yes"))

# Ctree
ctreeModel <- ctree(y ~ ., data = trainData)

# Generate predictions from the Ctree model
ctreePred <- predict(ctreeModel, newdata = testData, type = "response")

# Convert predictions to factor with the same levels as test_labels
ctreePred <- factor(ctreePred, levels = levels(test_labels))

# Compare the lengths directly
if(length(ctreePred) != length(test_labels)) {
  stop(paste("Length Mismatch: Predictions =", length(ctreePred), "Test Labels =", length(test_labels)))
}

# Compute the confusion matrix for the Ctree model
ctreeMatrix <- confusionMatrix(ctreePred, test_labels)

# Print the confusion matrix
print(ctreeMatrix)

# J48 Tree
j48Model <- J48(y ~ ., data = trainData)
j48Pred <- predict(j48Model, newdata = testData)
j48Pred <- factor(j48Pred, levels = levels(test_labels))
if(all(levels(j48Pred) == levels(test_labels))) {
  j48Matrix <- confusionMatrix(j48Pred, test_labels)
} else {
  stop("J48 Tree: Mismatch in factor levels between predictions and test labels.")
}

# Linear Classifier (Logistic Regression)
linearModel <- glm(y ~ ., data = trainData, family = "binomial")
linearPred <- predict(linearModel, newdata = testData, type = "response")
linearPred <- ifelse(linearPred > 0.5, "yes", "no")
linearPred <- factor(linearPred, levels = levels(test_labels))
if(all(levels(linearPred) == levels(test_labels))) {
  linearMatrix <- confusionMatrix(linearPred, test_labels)
} else {
  stop("Linear Classifier: Mismatch in factor levels between predictions and test labels.")
}

# k-Nearest Neighbour (k-NN)
knnModel <- knn(train = train_features, test = test_features, cl = train_labels, k = 5)
knnModel <- factor(knnModel, levels = levels(test_labels))
if(all(levels(knnModel) == levels(test_labels))) {
  knnMatrix <- confusionMatrix(knnModel, test_labels)
} else {
  stop("k-NN: Mismatch in factor levels between predictions and test labels.")
}

# Model Evaluation
results <- data.frame(Model = character(), Accuracy = numeric(), ErrorRate = numeric(), Precision = numeric(), Recall = numeric(), F1Score = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Evaluate each model and populate the results dataframe
models <- list(ctree = ctreeModel, j48 = j48Model, linear = linearModel, knn = knnModel)
for(model_name in names(models)) {
  model <- models[[model_name]]
  if(model_name == "knn") {
    pred <- model
  } else {
    pred_raw <- predict(model, newdata = testData, type = "response")
    pred <- ifelse(model_name == "linear", ifelse(pred_raw > 0.5, "yes", "no"), pred_raw)
  }
  
  # Ensure predictions are factors with correct levels
  pred <- factor(pred, levels = levels(test_labels))
  
  # Check for matching lengths and factor levels
  if(length(pred) != length(test_labels)) {
    stop(paste(model_name, "model: Mismatch in number of predictions and test labels."))
  }
  
  if(all(levels(pred) == levels(test_labels))) {
    confusionMatrix <- confusionMatrix(pred, test_labels)
    
    accuracy <- confusionMatrix$overall['Accuracy']
    errorRate <- 1 - accuracy
    precision <- confusionMatrix$byClass['Precision']
    recall <- confusionMatrix$byClass['Recall']
    f1Score <- 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(Model = model_name, Accuracy = accuracy, ErrorRate = errorRate, Precision = precision, Recall = recall, F1Score = f1Score))
  } else {
    stop(paste(model_name, "model: Mismatch in factor levels between predictions and test labels."))
  }
}

# Visualization with ggplot2
ggplot(results, aes(x = Model, y = Accuracy, fill = Model))
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Classifier Comparison Based on Accuracy", x = "Classifier", y = "Accuracy")
```

The error is as follows:
Error: ctree model: Mismatch in number of predictions and test labels.

I have tried a lot of debugging and comparing the values, lengths, and levels of the given dataset. What I have found which I believe is the error is that despite showing the values, lengths and levels of the dataset match, there is indeed a mismatch in the value for "pred". You will see in the attached image what the outputs are. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZucD.png). As you can see, the levels all match but the numbers for pred_raw and pred don't. Pred shows N/A while pred_raw has a two in it. Despite manually printing out each component and it showing that matches, in the output it shows otherwise.

If anyone has any insight as to why this is happening, or if they could run it and try to figure it out themselves, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.